# What symbol and variable really represent when I use them in nasm?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

What does the line : "`d: db 'hey',0xa`" represent.
I know `d` is a symbol but what does it mean when I use it like that: "`mov eax, d`"? Do I put the value or the address into `eax`? What does the symbol represent when I use it?

Secondly, to write output we must fill the ecx register with the pointer to the value, normally like this : "`mov ecx, [v1]`". But why do I have to put the bracket? Can't I just mov the value of the address in `ecx`?

Comment: In NASM `mov eax, d` puts the address of the `'hey', 0xa` string into `eax`.

Comment: You *can* just `mov ecx, v1`, if `v1` is a label on a `db`.  If you have a pointer *stored in memory* (like C `static char *v1 = d;` instead of just `static char d[] = "hey\n";`), then yeah you have to load it (memory source, i.e. square brackets), not just mov-immediate of a constant address to a register.  Without specifying what's at `v1`, the premise of your 2nd paragraph looks wrong.

Comment: Related: [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012) for x86-64